# Sending String value as parameter is getting Force Close error in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

i want to send text to my model class in android 
and model class is as

```
    public class ChatMessage {
    int id;
    String OriginalMsgThreadId;
    String SenderUserInfoId;
    String ReceiverUserInfoId;
    String MessageStatus;// Pending-Sent-Recieved-Read
    int isPending;
    String MessageText;
    String MediaURL;
    String MediaMIMEType;
    float MediaSize;
    String MediaName;
    String Latitude;
    String Longitude;
    String ThumbImage;
    String SendTimeStamp;
    String ReceiveTimeStamp;



    public ChatMessage() {
    }

    public ChatMessage(String originalMsgThreadId, String senderUserInfoId, String receiverUserInfoId, String messageStatus, int isPending, String messageText, String mediaURL, String mediaMIMEType, float mediaSize, String mediaName, String latitude, String longitude, String thumbImage, String sendTimeStamp, String receiveTimeStamp) {
        OriginalMsgThreadId = originalMsgThreadId;
        SenderUserInfoId = senderUserInfoId;
        ReceiverUserInfoId = receiverUserInfoId;
        MessageStatus = messageStatus;
        this.isPending = isPending;
        MessageText = messageText;
        MediaURL = mediaURL;
        MediaMIMEType = mediaMIMEType;
        MediaSize = mediaSize;
        MediaName = mediaName;
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
        ThumbImage = thumbImage;
        SendTimeStamp = sendTimeStamp;
        ReceiveTimeStamp = receiveTimeStamp;
    }
}
```

and the function where i am calling ChatMessage is as

```
private boolean sendChatMessage(){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        String messageText=chatText.getText().toString();
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(orgMsgThreadId, loginUserInfoId, receiverUserInfoId, "Sent", 1,  messageText, "", "", 0 , "", "", "", "", currentDateandTime, currentDateandTime);
        long messageId = db.SendMessage(chatMessage);
        chatMessageAdapter.add(chatMessage);
        SyncMessageToServer(chatMessage);

        if(messageId != 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and here is my SyncMessageToServer method

```
public boolean SyncMessageToServer(ChatMessage chatMessage){
    boolean sentStatus = false;
    String msgText=chatMessage.getMessageText();
    String fileUrl=chatMessage.getMediaURL();
    int isPending = chatMessage.getIsPending();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " = ---loginUserInfoId = " + chatMessage.getSenderUserInfoId() + " receiverUserInfoId = " + receiverUserInfoId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    chatText.setText("");

    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";

    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/AndroidApp/SendMessage?messageText="+msgText+"&senderUserInfoId="+loginUserInfoId+"&recieverUserInfoId="+receiverUserInfoId+"&url="+fileUrl+"&isGroupMsg="+false);

    try {
        response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
        str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"message sending Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
        //  GetMessage(receiverUserInfoId);
    } catch ( JSONException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

if i am writing "How are you" then its getting force close error 
but if i am writing "HowAreYou" then its running smoothly

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: 01-29 10:59:45.567  31689-31689/technovite.com.dbsyncetest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: technovite.com.dbsyncetest, PID: 31689
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 57: http://192.168.1.2/AndroidApp/SendMessage?messageText=how are u&senderUserInfoId=6456d7be-204e-e411-be9e-eca86bf55486&recieverUserInfoId=ac6e6f4f-7ce0-e311-b021-eca86bf5549a&url=&isGroupMsg=false
            at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)

Comment: show your SyncMessageToServer() method code and this time edit the question not in comment

Comment: Error clearly says that there is some unwanted character in your string so you need to encode your string using `URLEncoder` or just use `urstring.replace(" " , "%20");`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
public class ChatMessage {
        int id = 0;
        String OriginalMsgThreadId = "";
        String SenderUserInfoId = "";
        String ReceiverUserInfoId = "";
        String MessageStatus = "";// Pending-Sent-Recieved-Read
        int isPending = 0;
        String MessageText = "";
        String MediaURL = "";
        String MediaMIMEType = "";
        float MediaSize = 0.0f;
        String MediaName = "";
        String Latitude = "";
        String Longitude = "";
        String ThumbImage = "";
        String SendTimeStamp = "";
        String ReceiveTimeStamp = "";

        public ChatMessage(String originalMsgThreadId, String senderUserInfoId,
                String receiverUserInfoId, String messageStatus, int isPending,
                String messageText, String mediaURL, String mediaMIMEType,
                float mediaSize, String mediaName, String latitude,
                String longitude, String thumbImage, String sendTimeStamp,
                String receiveTimeStamp) {
            this.OriginalMsgThreadId = originalMsgThreadId;
            this.SenderUserInfoId = senderUserInfoId;
            this.ReceiverUserInfoId = receiverUserInfoId;
            this.MessageStatus = messageStatus;
            this.isPending = isPending;
            this.MessageText = messageText;
            this.MediaURL = mediaURL;
            this.MediaMIMEType = mediaMIMEType;
            this.MediaSize = mediaSize;
            this.MediaName = mediaName;
            this.Latitude = latitude;
            this.Longitude = longitude;
            this.ThumbImage = thumbImage;
            this.SendTimeStamp = sendTimeStamp;
            this.ReceiveTimeStamp = receiveTimeStamp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also Add getter setter method to get all values where you want to get.

Comment: And replace   str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8"); with  str =EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).toString();

Comment: this isn't working. please provide me how can i encode my url

Comment: You are using get method or post method here.?

Comment: HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String myURL = "http://192.168.1.2/AndroidApp/SendMessage?messageText="+msgText+"&senderUserInfoId="+loginUserInfoId+"&recieverUserInfoId="+receiverUserInfoId+"&url="+fileUrl+"&isGroupMsg="+false;
        
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(myURL);

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str =EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).toString();

        }

Comment: Use This.      String url = "http://192.168.1.2/AndroidApp/SendMessage?messageText="
    + msgText + "&senderUserInfoId=" + loginUserInfoId
    + "&recieverUserInfoId=" + receiverUserInfoId + "&url="
    + fileUrl + "&isGroupMsg=" + false;
  HttpGet myConnection = new HttpGet(url);

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my SyncMessageToServer method

```
public boolean SyncMessageToServer(ChatMessage chatMessage){
        boolean sentStatus = false;
        String msgText=chatMessage.getMessageText();
        String fileUrl=chatMessage.getMediaURL();
        int isPending = chatMessage.getIsPending();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " = ---loginUserInfoId = " + chatMessage.getSenderUserInfoId() + " receiverUserInfoId = " + receiverUserInfoId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        chatText.setText("");

        JSONObject json = null;
        String str = "";

        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/AndroidApp/SendMessage");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("messageText", msgText));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senderUserInfoId", loginUserInfoId));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("recieverUserInfoId", receiverUserInfoId));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", fileUrl));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isGroupMsg", "false"));
            myConnection.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str =EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"message sending Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
            //  GetMessage(receiverUserInfoId);
        } catch ( JSONException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
```